# Fibonacci Sequence Implementation Not Behaving As Expected

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to print the first 5 numbers in the Fibonacci sequence starting with 1 and 2. I expect this code to print `1,2,3,5,8` when I click the button, but somehow it only prints the last number which is 8 in this case. And if I click the button many times after that, it always prints `2`. Why does it behave that way?

```js
/*
 Fibonacci sequence is calculated by the formula An = An-1 + An-2
 @param prev An-2
 @param next An-1
 @param n the first n numbers to print
*/
var count = 0; // keeps track of which number we are on
function fibonacci(prev, next, n) {
    // Need to subtract 2 or else it will print the first 7 numbers instead of 5 
    return count++ < n - 2 ? fibonacci(Math.max(prev,next), prev+next, n) + "," : next;
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(fibonacci(1, 2, 5));
});
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: hint: where do you reset `count`?

Comment: More accurately it prints `8,,,`

Comment: You're not adding `prev` to your string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only use `console.log` with the last result. If you want to log all of them, you should use it inside the recursive function.

And the second time you click the button, it doesn't work because `count` is global. You could reset it to `0` inside the event listener, but better avoid globals.

```js
function fibonacci(current, next, n) {
  if(n > 0) {
    console.log(current);
    fibonacci(next, current + next, n-1);
  }
}
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  fibonacci(1, 2, 5);
});
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: It looks like the OP might want a single string as the result. Maybe include that variation? `var fib = function(a,b,n){ return n === 1 ? a : a + ',' + fib(b, a+b, n-1); };`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you Oriol and @FizzyTea

Answer (score 1):

You `console.log()` the return value of `fibonacci(1,2,5)`, which is exactly one number. You do not print anything anywhere in your recursive function calls. So, obvioulsly, only tha final result of your function will be printed.
If you want intermediary results, `console.log(prev)` before your return statement in `fibonacci()`.

This solves your first issue.

---

For the second issue, you need to keep in mind how your variables work. `count`is defined outside of the fuction `fibonacci`, and therefore not automatically reset or anything just because the function ends. This means: after the funciton ran for the first time (and as a side effect, setting `count` to `3`), the variable `count` will keep it's value `3`. The next time you run the function, `count++ < n - 2` will evaluate to `false` right away, because `4 < 3` is false. So it will return `next`, which is `2` on the first iteration.

To fix this, restrucutre your function in a way that it resets `count` to `0` when the last recursion is done, before it returns `next` ( you cannot do this within the ternary statement, you need to refractore it to a regular if-else)

Answer (score 0):

Let's use newest technologies.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fibonacci</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        'use strict';
        function* fibonacci(cur, nxt) {//generator function
            //let cur=0,nxt=1;
            yield cur;
            yield nxt;
            while(true){
                [cur,nxt]=[nxt,cur+nxt];//swap
                yield nxt;
            }
        }

        function getNumbers(){
            var a = document.getElementById('cur').value-0;//instead of parseInt
            var b = document.getElementById('nxt').value-0;
            var n = document.getElementById('cnt').value-0;
            var fi = fibonacci(a,b);//init generator
            var fiNums = [];//init result array
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                var tmp=fi.next();//{value:1, done:false}
                fiNums.push(tmp.value);
            }
            //output result
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = fiNums.join(', ');
        }

//get all series in once
function getNumbersOld(){
    var a = document.getElementById('cur').value-0;
    var b = document.getElementById('nxt').value-0;
    var n = document.getElementById('cnt').value-0;
    var fiNums = [b,a];
    for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        fiNums.unshift(fiNums[0]+fiNums[1]);
    }
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = fiNums.reverse().join(', ');
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Generate Fibonacci series <br />
Current:<input type="number" id="cur" value="1" />
    Next:<input type="number" id="nxt" value="1" />
    Count:<input type="number" id="cnt" value="5" />
    <button onclick="getNumbersOld()">Get Numbers</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your implementation is overly complicated unnecessarily. I prefer recursion over loops any day. If you can get in done in one line. Then do it in one line

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers regarding the global variable and how I didn't print the result of each recursive call from others, I was able to obtain a final correct solution to my problem.

```
function fibanocci(prev, next, n) {
    /* 
       n - 2 is here so it will print the first n numbers in the Fibonacci sequence
       instead of n + 2 numbers because we have to account for the 2 initial numbers, 
       1 and 2 in this case, and I don't want the client to account for these 2 initial
       numbers themselves. Math.abs(n-2) so the recursion will stop when n is 1 so the 
       call stack will not get bloated and throw an exception.
    */ 
    return n > Math.abs(n-2) ? prev + "," + fibanocci(Math.max(prev,next), prev + next, --n) : prev;
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
   console.log(fibonacci(1, 2, 5));
});
```